# Connecting to remote server ps.outlook.com failed

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I use the below code to connect to office365 and retrive mailbox information using c# with remote powershell.

```
strExchange2010PSURI = "https://ps.outlook.com/PowerShell-LiveID?PSVersion=3.0";
strAccountName = "uuuu@kcstaff.onmicrosoft.com";
strAccountPwd = "ppp";

public DataTable GetMailboxes(string searchMailbox)
{
    DataTable dt = null;
    List<string> mailboxes = new List<string>();
    Command psCmd1 = new Command("Get-Mailbox");
    psCmd1.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("Identity", "*" + searchMailbox + "*"));
    Collection<PSObject> psExchMailboxInfo = fnGetPSData(psCmd1, null);

    if (psExchMailboxInfo != null && psExchMailboxInfo.Count > 0)
    {
//logic to get the mailbox details in a datatable
        dt = GetMailboxInfo(mailboxes);
    }

    return dt;
}

private Collection<PSObject> fnGetPSData(Command psCmd1, Command psCmd2)
{
    Pipeline psPipeLine = null;
    Runspace psRunSpace = null;
    WSManConnectionInfo psConnInfo = null;
    var varSecurePwd = new SecureString();
    try
    {
        foreach (var c in strAccountPwd)
        {
            varSecurePwd.AppendChar(c);
        }
        PSCredential psCreds = new PSCredential(strAccountName, varSecurePwd);
        psConnInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(strExchange2010PSURI), "Microsoft.Exchange", psCreds);
        psConnInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;
        psRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(psConnInfo);

        psRunSpace.Open();
        psPipeLine = psRunSpace.CreatePipeline();

        if (psCmd1 != null)
        {
            psPipeLine.Commands.Add(psCmd1);
        }
        if (psCmd2 != null)
        {
            psPipeLine.Commands.Add(psCmd2);
        }
        Collection<PSObject> psObjects = psPipeLine.Invoke();

        return psObjects;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (psPipeLine != null && psPipeLine.Commands != null)
        {
            psPipeLine.Commands.Clear();
            psPipeLine.Dispose();
        }

        if (psRunSpace != null)
        {
            psRunSpace.Close();
            psRunSpace.Dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

It works in my development environment but when I try the same in production I get "Connecting to remote server ps.outlook.com failed with the following error message: Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.".

Can anyone help?

Comment: firewall between prod server and the web? it is common after all for servers not to have direct internet access

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the authentication mechanism doesn't work. I would avoid the use of ConnInfo and try this instead after opening the PSRunspace:

```
Command PSCredentialCommand = new Command("Set-Variable");
PSCredentialCommand.Parameters.Add("Name", "PSCredentials");
PSCredentialCommand.Parameters.Add("Value", pscreds);

pipeline.Commands.Add(PSCredentialCommand);
pipeline.Commands.AddScript(script);
```

where script content is like:

```
$O365Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName 'Microsoft.Exchange' -ConnectionUri 'https://ps.outlook.com/powershell' -Credential $PSCredentials -Authentication 'Basic' -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $O365Session -AllowClobber | Out-Null
```

etc.